# Determine if the series converge or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to determine whether this series converge or not - 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{^4\sqrt n-\ 4}{n^\frac{3}{2}+6}$$
I would like to get an hint - I thought about the ratio test , 
but it seems too long.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks an awful lot like $\root 4\of n/ n^{3/2}$ to me ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the comparison test? This function seems ugly to do at any rate...

If you compare with the sum of $\frac{n^{\frac{1}{4}}}{n^{\frac{6}{4}}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}}$, which is a p series with $p>1$ and so converges.

**EDIT:** Rather, you should note that each term of your infinite series is less than each term of the $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{5}{4}}}$ series, which converges, and so the original series converges.

Comment: Can I use the comparison test while the series isn't positive for all n ?

Comment: @BarakMi You can always can if the series sequence is positive *for almost all* $\;n\;$

Comment: and my explanation should be that for some n the series is always positive?

Comment: Think about it this way. If $n>4^4$, then DCT holds for those terms. Consequently the infinite series beginning at $n=4^4$ and going to infinity converges to a finite value. Now note that the sum from 1 to $n=4^4$ is already finite. The sum of two finite quantities is finite therefore the infinite series is finite; that is, it converged